# Remove blue outline on links when clicking, but keep the outline for TAB selection (accessibility)

Tags: css, focus, accessibility, selection, outline

I have a Burger Menu Button which is selectable via TAB. When I click on it and the menu opens up the burger has this blue outline to make it clear that it is focused.
I don't want to remove that blue outline, because it helps vision impaired people and for tab selection it is also great, but is there a smart way to remove the blue outline only when someone clicks on it via mouse. Just asthetics...

Thanks for your answer.

cheers

Comment: The best solution for this problem is from guys from Facebook, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402576/enable-focus-only-on-keyboard-use-or-tab-press#answer-51093815

Comment: By the way, I solved it with this package: https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input
If the input source is the keyboard (=tab) I can style things differently compared to input === mouse.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, the blue outline is here for accessibility reasons.

If you click on the element, the keyboard focus will also move to that element.

So users have to know that the keyboard focus has been moved to that element.

Some people with disabilities may want to jump to a particular tab using the mouse, but then use their keyboard for easiness reasons.

Answer (score 1):

**js**:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('mouse');
});
$('#element').blur(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('mouse'){
     $(this).removeClass('mouse');
  }
});
```

**css**:

```
.mouse{
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the jquery click function include keyboard clicks as well? If so, mousedown/up might be better than click/blur.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the question, try:

`.myButton:active {outline: none;}`

Comment: But this would remove the outline when the user tabs to it too right? Which is not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution, in plain Javascript, that works back to IE 10.

This answer is similar to @kuba's answer.  Add/remove a class using JS to detect a mouse click or a tab button press.

javascript:

```
var htmlElement = document.querySelector('html');

document.addEventListener('click', function(){
  htmlElement.classList.add('clicking');
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    htmlElement.classList.remove('clicking');
  }
});
```

Then turn off outline on :focus when the clicking class exists

CSS:

```
html.clicking .targetElement:focus {
   outline: none;
}

/* 
  or you can try dealing with all visibly focusable elements from the start.  I'm not sure if this is all of them, but it's good starting point.
*/

html.clicking a:focus,
html.clicking button:focus,
html.clicking input:focus,
html.clicking textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Browser Compatibility:

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Browser_Compatibility) IE 8+
[element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) IE 10+

jQuery alternative if you need to support browsers older than IE10.

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
  $('html').addClass('clicking');
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(){
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    $('html').removeClass('clicking');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using an SVG as a button (for a star rating system). The solution I found is to use a wrapper div around whatever object is getting this focus outline.

Put the button logic (onclick/onkeyup) in the wrapper div, and the outline will not show up on a click, but it will still allow a user to tab to it.

Answer (score -1):

Well you may want to do it this way:

```
div:active, div:focus{
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

and maybe:

```
*{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Comment: you're offering the exact opposite to the solution he's asking for

Comment: Oh, isn't his question "is there a smart way to remove the blue outline only when someone clicks on it via mouse" ?

Comment: No. His question is when to remove while leaving the outline for the tabs. If you remove the outline with the :active it will also remove it when ... active, on tab :p