# Show focus outline only on tabbing not on mouse click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on ReactJS web app, and I am adding specific outline style, but the outline shows up when a user clicks on it using a mouse. How can I make the outline to appear only for tabbing?

```
const Test = styled.div`
 &:focus {
  outline: 1px solid red;
 }
`;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable :focus only on keyboard use (or tab press)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402576/enable-focus-only-on-keyboard-use-or-tab-press)

Answer (score 1):

There is already an excellent answer to this question:
[Enable :focus only on keyboard use (or tab press)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402576/enable-focus-only-on-keyboard-use-or-tab-press)

Take a look, the answer is very detailed. have fun coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `focus-active` pseudo-class. Check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) for that.

```
const Test = styled.div`
 &:focus-visible {        /* <--- HERE IS THE CHANGE */
  outline: 1px solid red;
 }
`;
```

As Sitian Liu said, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402576/enable-focus-only-on-keyboard-use-or-tab-press) for a deep answer.