# Remove outline on :active & :focus but not on :focus only

Tags: javascript, html, css, fluent-kit

I use [datatables from fluent kit](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/docs/content/table/#initialization) and the pagination, when clicked (`:active`) is highlighted with:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
```

I want it gone, but only when clicked. I want the effect to work only for the `:focus` done with keyboard, a `TAB` key. I don't think it is possible with CSS only. If it is, that's awesome. If not, javascript / jquery solution is acceptable.

Here's simplified example of the code:

```css
.pagination {
  padding: 20px;
}

.pagination a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.pagination a:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
}

.pagination a:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

Use `TAB` to change focus between the `<a>` links to see what I mean.

---

**EDIT**

As it is the external plugin, I don't want to use another HTML elements for that to work, like in [Enable :focus only on keyboard use (or tab press)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402576/enable-focus-only-on-keyboard-use-or-tab-press).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable :focus only on keyboard use (or tab press)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402576/enable-focus-only-on-keyboard-use-or-tab-press)

Comment: You can combine both: `a:active:focus`, and also exclude one `a:focus:not(:active)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On `TAB` click `e.key === 'Tab'`  (or `e.keyCode=9` in ASCI code)**

Learn here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Use this function:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Tab') {
   console.log('tab is clicked!')
  }
});
```

```css
.pagination {
  padding: 20px;
}

.pagination a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.pagination a:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
}

.pagination a:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

**OR only by css**

this plugin:https://github.com/ten1seven/track-focus 
**in css:**

```
body[data-whatinput="keyboard"] a:focus {
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px red;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: I don't think JS is necessary for this.

Comment: for catch TAB click event, yes! but he/she can use the plugin

Comment: Why are you using jQuery inside your event listeners? Also, the usage of `keyCode` is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick. Eh I cant upvote you, not enough reputation. Will do when hit 15! Thanks again.

Comment: It is fine happy to help:)

Comment: @connexo see my edit and feel free to edit my answer to improove it

Comment: MDN on `keyCode`: Deprecated
This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: I think use `event.which==9` is better . Am i right?

Comment: Why not read the docs? And no, you're even more wrong with `event.which`.

Comment: @connexo Thank you for bringing this to my attention.. I edited answer

Answer (score 0):

**I think you might be this code here**

```css
.pagination {
  padding: 20px;
}

.pagination a {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.pagination a:focus {
  outline:0;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

.pagination a:active {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
</div>
```